# Is it possible to remove CommonPasswordValidator when you register an account in Django?

Tags: python, django, validation, authorization

When a password is too common, Django raises the "The password is too common" error. I wanna remove this validation. Is it possible? And how to do it?

Comment: You might want to read about [Password validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/passwords/#password-validation) in the Django documentation.

Answer (score 1):

```
    AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
        },

        #remove this from settings.py
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
        }, 


        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
        },
    ]
```

Comment: Do developers do it when they want users could create a simple password '11111111q'?

Comment: It certainly makes you site's security weaker. It's your decision.